# R - Assign increasing index to every occurrence of a value in a column grouped by another column

Tags: r, indexing, group-by, counter

My data is like this:

```
Time| V1 | V2
T01 | A  | 1
T02 | A  | 1
T03 | A  | 2
T04 | A  | 2
T05 | A  | 3
T06 | A  | 3
T07 | A  | 4
T08 | A  | 4
T09 | A  | 1
T10 | A  | 1
T11 | A  | 2
T12 | A  | 2
T13 | A  | 3
T14 | A  | 3
T15 | A  | 4
T16 | A  | 4
```

Every row has a unique timestamp in the 'Time' column. The data is sorted on this already. I want to create a new column that assigns an increasing counter to V2, grouped by V1. For example, all rows where '1' in V2 occurs for the first time should be assigned index 1. The second time '1' occurs, it should be assigned index 2, and so on... Like this:

```
Time| V1 | V2 | V3
T01 | A  | 1  | 1 
T02 | A  | 1  | 1
T03 | A  | 2  | 1
T04 | A  | 2  | 1
T05 | A  | 3  | 1
T06 | A  | 3  | 1
T07 | A  | 4  | 1
T08 | A  | 4  | 1
T09 | A  | 1  | 2
T10 | A  | 1  | 2
T11 | A  | 2  | 2
T12 | A  | 2  | 2
T13 | A  | 3  | 2
T14 | A  | 3  | 2
T15 | A  | 4  | 2
T16 | A  | 4  | 2
```

The indices for V2 should be grouped by V1. So, if the value in V1 changes, the indexing of V2 values in V3 should start afresh. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't get why you have observations duplicated without incrementing V3. Why doesn't row 2 have V3 = 2?

Comment: @camille - i think it's a variation on run-length-encoding. Like a cumulative sum of every run of 1's.

Comment: @camille, I've updated my question to clarify - every row has a unique timestamp. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a data table solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)
dd[, temp := rleid(V2), by = .(V1)][, result := as.integer(factor(temp)), by = V2]
dd
#     V1 V2 V3 temp result
#  1:  A  1  1    1      1
#  2:  A  1  1    1      1
#  3:  A  2  1    2      1
#  4:  A  2  1    2      1
#  5:  A  3  1    3      1
#  6:  A  3  1    3      1
#  7:  A  4  1    4      1
#  8:  A  4  1    4      1
#  9:  A  1  2    5      2
# 10:  A  1  2    5      2
# 11:  A  2  2    6      2
# 12:  A  2  2    6      2
# 13:  A  3  2    7      2
# 14:  A  3  2    7      2
# 15:  A  4  2    8      2
# 16:  A  4  2    8      2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
    group_by(V1) %>%
    mutate(ind = with(rle(V2), rep(ave(values, values, FUN = seq_along), lengths)))
```